# Type mismatch error when creating a vba array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to drop a range of cells straight into an array to run some calculations. The range will always be A8:E?, but I never know how many total rows there will be. One of the columns contains string values that I need for determining conditions. I set a variable to find the last row (and no, this data never has any blanks so the method to set it works just fine). This is what I have"

```
    Sub use_arr()
    Dim rw As Integer

    rw = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A8").End(xlDown).Row

    Dim myArr()

    myArr = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A8:E" & rw)

    End Sub
```

But it keeps throwing a "Run_time error '13'" at me.

Arrays are still new to me, someone suggested using them instead of looping through cells for faster execution. So I'm still figuring this out.

Comment: If your data is large, I think the type of rw should be long.

Comment: Value is required when declaring a dynamic array, and value is not required when it is a static array. That is, if you declare dim myArr, it becomes a static array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either declare `myArr` just as a `Variant`, not an array, or specify the `Value` property of the range:

```
myArr = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A8:E" & rw).Value
```